# Weird results when testing model associations in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model, an Event Model, an Event Priority Model and a Event Type Model. Model code as follows:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event_priority
  belongs_to :event_type

  attr_accessible :name, :raised_date, :location, :description, :longtitude, :latitude
  attr_protected :raised_user_id, :event_priority_id, :event_type_id
end

class EventPriority < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :events
  has_many :users, :through => :events
  has_many :event_types, :through => :events

end

class EventType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :events
  has_many :users, :through => :events
  has_many :event_priorities, :through => :events

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :full_name, :password, password_confirmation

  has_many :events, :foreign_key => "raised_user_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :event_priorities, :through => :events
  has_many :event_types, :through => :events

end
```

Can anyone explain the inability to get from the Event back to the User in the following rails console example?

```
irb(main):027:0> @user = User.find(2)
=> Returns the user with an ID of 2.

irb(main):028:0> @user.events
=> Returns all events for that user.

irb(main):029:0> @user.events.first.user
=> nil --HUH????

irb(main):031:0> @event = @user.events.first
=> Saves and returns the first event created by the user.

irb(main):032:0> @event.user
=> nil --Again, WHY??

irb(main):033:0> @events = Event.all
=> Saves and returns all events.

irb(main):035:0> @events.first.user
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.first
        from (irb):35
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.
6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:279 -- AGAIN, WHY?
```

Comment: Can you post your model assocations for `:user` and `:event`?

Comment: Ok I get it! So a :custom_key has to be specified on BOTH sides of a Rails model association, in my case has_many and belongs_to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a good reason for not just using `user_id` as the foreign key in the `events` table? (that's what is causing your problem)

Try adding the `foreign_key` option in the Event class as well

Answer (score 0):

You can get from a User to an Event because you've told the "User has_many Events" association to use your custom foreign key.  You can't get back, because you haven't told the "Event belongs_to User" association to use that custom key.  It therefore expects the default key of "user_id", which it can't find, so it can't get back.

I'm surprised it handles it gracefully (by returning nil), actually - I would have expected it to throw an exception at that point.

And I'm afraid I have no idea about your second problem.  I can only guess that you somehow set `@events` to `nil` on the missing IRB line #34...

Hope that helps!

Comment: So I should move :foreign_key => "raised_user_id" to the Events model or should it be in both the User and Events models?

Comment: @raouldeveloper - It would need to be in both places.  However, if you just used the attribute `user_id` you wouldn't need it in either place (see klochner's answer).  Any reason you can't do that?

Comment: OK got it! The offical Rails guide on associations was not clear that the foreign key must be in the code in both models. I suppose it is better to use the expected user_id in the future... Thanks a million!